# How to show progress bar while loading, using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown box. When the user selects a value from the dropdown box, it performs a query to retrieve the data from the database, and shows the results in the front end using ajax. It takes a little bit of time, so during this time, I want to show a progress bar. I have searched, and I have found numerous tutorials on creating progress bars for uploads, but I haven't liked any. Can anybody provides some helpful guidance for me?

My ajax code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
      var clientid=$("#client").val();

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php",
            data:"title="+clientid,
            success:function(data){
             $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use a progress bar since the database query doesn't return anything until it's finished. You could have a simple loading animation though.

Comment: thanks for your reply can you guide me how to do that .

Comment: You can show/hide a div containing the animation with the [ajaxstart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxstop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events.

Comment: Do you have a timeout for the AJAX request - or a rough idea of how long the request can be long at most?

Answer (score 81):

This **[link](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)** describes how you can add a progress event listener to the xhr object using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        // Upload progress
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with upload progress
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
       }, false);
       
       // Download progress
       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               // Do something with download progress
               console.log(percentComplete);
           }
       }, false);
       
       return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        // Do something success-ish
    }
});
```

Comment: This no longer works with jQuery 1.9.3+. It goes into the event listener once at 1 percent complete and never hits it again. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try a loader with a timeout using jquery. set the timer on ajaxstart and stop on ajaxStop

Comment: Its not working. What is `upload` here in xhr.upload.addEventListener?

Comment: I got mine working by adding 2 lines and it work multiple times. see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799932/ajax-loading-bar-function?noredirect=1#comment57343415_34799932

Comment: Works good, but only if response is small like < 10kb, otherwise i get lengthComputable: false..

Comment: This worked for me after multiplying `percentComplete` with 100. thanks for the solution.

Comment: var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total; is actually: var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;

Comment: The question was about a XHR query, not a XHR upload/download. The XHR query does not return a computable progress.

Comment: Simply adding that this code indeed does work with jQuery 3.5.1 at the time of writing this comment.

Answer (score 23):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
      var clientid=$("#client").val();
     //show the loading div here
    $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php",
        data:"title="+clientid,
        success:function(data){
             $("#result").html(data);
          //hide the loading div here
        }
    }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Or you can also do this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        // show loader on start
        $("#loader").css("display","block");
    }).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        // hide loader on success
        $("#loader").css("display","none");
    });
```

Comment: what if there are other ajax request running on the same page ? how can we do this to a specific ajax request.

Comment: @prime, assign it to a variable.

Comment: @Suvash he asked for progress bar which shows the realtime completion progress of request, not the loader which have you answered.

Answer (score 20):

Basically you need to have loading image Download free one from here http://www.ajaxload.info/

```
$(function() {
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
      var clientid=$("#client").val();
      $('#loadingmessage').show();

    $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php",
        data:"title="+clientid,
        success:function(data){
             $('#loadingmessage').hide();
             $("#result").html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
});
```

On html body

```
<div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
       <img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'/>
</div>
```

Probably this could help you

Comment: +1 Very simple and straight for Ajax request. Worked for me. Not used the download image option as I'm using progress control for universal apps.

Comment: Simple. No hassle, one line solution.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example that's working for me with MVC and Javascript in the Razor.  The first function calls an action via ajax on my controller and passes two parameters.

```
        function redirectToAction(var1, var2)
        {
            try{

                var url = '../actionnameinsamecontroller/' + routeId;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data: { param1: var1, param2: var2 },
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });

            }
            catch(err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Use the ajaxStart to start your progress bar code.

```
           $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            try
            {
                // showing a modal
                $("#progressDialog").modal();

                var i = 0;
                var timeout = 750;

                (function progressbar()
                {
                    i++;
                    if(i < 1000)
                    {
                        // some code to make the progress bar move in a loop with a timeout to 
                        // control the speed of the bar
                        iterateProgressBar();
                        setTimeout(progressbar, timeout);
                    }
                }
                )();
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
```

When the process completes close the progress bar

```
        $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
            // hide the progress bar
            $("#progressDialog").modal('hide');
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#wait').show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#wait').hide();
    });
    $(document).ajaxError(function () {
        $('#wait').hide();
    });   
});
```

```html
<div id="wait" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 100px; left: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 10000; text-align: center;">
            <img src="../images/loading_blue2.gif" width="45" height="45" alt="Loading..." style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

After much searching a way to show a progress bar just to make the most elegant charging could not find any way that would serve my purpose. Check the actual status of the request showed demaziado complex and sometimes snippets not then worked created a very simple way but it gives me the experience seeking (or almost), follows the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : url,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 10000,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.my-box').html('<div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div></div>');
        $('.progress-bar').animate({width: "30%"}, 100);
    },
    success: function(data){  
        if(data == 'Unauthorized.'){
            location.href = 'logout';
        }else{
            $('.progress-bar').animate({width: "100%"}, 100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.progress-bar').css({width: "100%"});
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.my-box').html(data);
                }, 100);
            }, 500);
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, err) {
        alert((status == "timeout") ? "Timeout" : "error: " + request + status + err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that are already many answers written for this solution however I want to show another javascript method (dependent on JQuery) **in which you simply need to include ONLY a single JS File without any dependency on CSS or Gif Images** in your code and that will take care of all progress bar related animations that happens during Ajax Request. 
You need to simnply pass javascript function like this

```
var objGlobalEvent = new RegisterGlobalEvents(true, "");
```

[image: Preview of Fiddle Loader Type]

Here is the working fiddle for the code. https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/c7wukc41/3/

Comment: @searchengine27 This screenshot is NOT for reading code. It was posted to let you know the **graphic preview** of the loader. If you can notice then I have **also included link of code fiddle** on which clicking you'll get the whole code.

Comment: This is more than 400kb... pretty bad solution.

Comment: @JuanFernandoz If Size is issue then you can replace inline embed image with your  external gif src .

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this

**CSS**

```
html {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
html, body {
    /* For the loading indicator to be vertically centered ensure */
    /* the html and body elements take up the full viewport */
    min-height: 100%;
}
html.loading {
    /* Replace #333 with the background-color of your choice */
    /* Replace loading.gif with the loading image of your choice */
    background: #333 url('/Images/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;

    /* Ensures that the transition only runs in one direction */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0;
    transition: background-color 0;
}
body {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
html.loading body {
    /* Make the contents of the body opaque during loading */
    opacity: 0;

    /* Ensures that the transition only runs in one direction */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0;
    transition: opacity 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).ajaxStart(function () {     
       $("html").addClass("loading");
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {        
        $("html").removeClass("loading");
    });
    $(document).ajaxError(function () {       
        $("html").removeClass("loading");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this since it's simpler and more useful.

```
<input id="datainput" type="text">
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="examplebutton"></button>
<script>
    $("#examplebutton").click(function(){
        let data=$("#datainput").val(); 
        $("#result").html("Please Wait..");  // it starts working when the button is clicked
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"../ajax/xyz.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{data:data},
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#result").html(result);  // When the data comes, the text will be deleted and the data will come.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you

```
 $.ajax({
  type:"post",
            url:"clientnetworkpricelist/yourfile.php",
        data:"title="+clientid,
  beforeSend: function(  ) {
    // load your loading fiel here
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    //hide your loading file here
  });
```

Comment: Not close to what the op was asking for. he wants to display the progress as it loads, not just a loading gif.

Answer (score 0):

Well this will definitely work.
Here we go...

```
function yourFunction(){
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loading').show();
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            //your ajax code goes here...
            $('#loading').hide();           
        }, 500);

    }, 300);
}
```

You can set css to your progress bar according to your requirement. Hide this div by default.

```
<div id="loading">
    <img id="loading-image" src="img-src" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```