# How to show progress bar when calling AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile app using `phonegap` (`JQ + Html` ). In my app, consuming `REST` webservice using `AJAX` calls.When service invoke, I am showing a progress bar animated GIF image . The problem is, browser freezes when calling AJAX. So the progress bar is not showing.

In ‘`beforeSend`’ i am showing the progress bar image and after ‘`complete`’ i am hiding the progress bar image.

I am also trying `async: true` . But it execute service as asynchronously. In my app,  asynchronous execution is not suit. Because asynchronous execution will not wait for ajax executing. My app should wait until the ajax execution complete. In that process time I want show progress bar.

Here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    accepts: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        StartPBar():
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(RQ),
    async: false,
    url: URL,
    complete: function() {
        stopPBar();
    },
    success: function(res, status, xhr) {
        try {
            RS = res;
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Excpetion " + errorThrown + XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Any suggestion to show the progress bar stay on screen until the process is fully complete? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use search? Possible duplication is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax

Comment: in order to show progress it would be required to make `async: true`. And what do u mean by parallel execution

Comment: @iJay Hi.. I mean asynchronously execution. question updated..

Comment: @Pavlo have you read my full question.. dont read only title. Thanks

Comment: @bala try to set `async:true`

Comment: @iJay I am also trying async: true . But it execute service as asynchronously. In my app, asynchronously execution is not suit

Comment: in order for the progress bar to work ..u have to use `async:true`. And why is asyn execution of service not suited in ur app. Can u elaborate. May be we can fix dat

Comment: @iJay In my app,  asynchronous execution is not suit. Because asynchronous execution will not wait for ajax executing. My app should wait until the ajax execution complete. In that process time I want show progress bar.

Comment: @bala do u have any other parallel AJAX calls ??

Comment: @iJay No.. I have a single Ajax call

Comment: you want to show progress bar until ur ajax execution completes ..rite...simply set `async:true` and call `stopPBar(); ` in success after ur code

Comment: @iJay I am calling ajax method to get some results from web server.
If i set `async:true` my page load without result.

Comment: @bala Dats fine. U show progress bar until results are fetched and populated in the page. Which happens in the suceess callback i believe. At the end of that do `stopPBar();` in the success callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you verify your javascript code.

Remove this code.

```
beforeSend: function() {
        StartPBar():
    },
```

Replace your jquery mobile with this one `jQuery Mobile 1.4.0-rc.1`

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js

Replace your code with this one.

```
$.mobile.loading('show');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    accepts: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(RQ),
    async: false,
    url: URL,
    complete: function() {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },
    success: function(res, status, xhr) {
        try {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
            RS = res;
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        alert("Excpetion " + errorThrown + XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `async: true`, the `async: false` will freeze the browser until the request is completed. Also move the `async: true` before  `beforeSend` method.

The `async: true`, when supported by browser, basically means: browser will send data asynchronous and will not block or wait other actions from executing. This is the only in my opinion way to show the progress bar indicator. Because (from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)):

> **Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,**
>   disabling any actions while the request is active.

Comment: User said, async true is not suit with his app

Comment: `browser will send data asynchronous and will not block or wait other actions from executing.`
My app should wait until the execution complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until ajax requests done, you can do it also with `async:true` like;

```
StartPBar():
$.when(runAjax()).done(function(result) {
    // result conatins responseText, status, and jqXHR
    stopPBar();
});

function runAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(RQ),
        async: true,
        url: URL,
        success: function (res, status, xhr) {
            try {

                RS = res;

            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Excpetion " + errorThrown + XMLHttpRequest);
        }

    });
}
```

In this example, when ajax request completed, progressbar stop function will be called.

Comment: However, after `var ajaxResult = runAjax();` `stopPBar` will work?

Comment: yes.. actually `startPBar()` and `stopPBAr()` functions are called but it is not display.. because during ajax call freezes the whole browser.

Comment: @bala if you want to wait until ajax request completed, you can do that with also async call. See my updated answer