# .ajaxSubmit from the jquery.form.js not working with data option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using the plugin `jquery.form.js` and I want to `programmatically` submit a form and include a file with it. The code and options I have set up with work with $.ajax but not `.ajaxSubmit`. According to the `jquery.form.js` documentation you can pass any standard `$.ajax` options to `.ajaxSubmit` but I can't seem to get it to work. I'd like to use `.ajaxSubmit` if possible so I can utilize some of the other features it offers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file-form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $("<form style='display:none;' method='post' action='video_upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
        var fd = new FormData();    
        fd.append('uploadedfile', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

        var options = {
            url: 'video_upload.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                alert('start');
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
        //form.ajaxSubmit(options);

        return false;
    }); 

});
```

Running `$.ajax(options)` works but `form.ajaxSubmit(options)` doesn't. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code of the method `ajaxSubmit` - http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js you can see that the property `data` of the options is serialised/deserialised and converted several times. So most likely the content really submitted will be quite different from what happens in `.ajax` call. Later on the `ajaxSubmit` collects the files from form and submits them differently.

Basically, for me the specifying data while submitting with ajaxSubmit goes against the concept of this plugin, which is described as "The main methods, ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit, gather information from the form element to determine how to manage the submit process." Idiomatic way of using `ajaxSubmit` would be applying this method for the form with controls.

Comment: So for my needs would you suggest that I just use the .ajax call? Mostly I wanted to use the ajaxSubmit so it would be easier to create a progress bar but I should be able to create one using .ajax. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If ajax works well for you then there is no need to use ajaxCall. See here for the progress bar examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax