# Progress indicator for filesize

Tags: javascript

I have a file "file.json" that I know is 1MB. Is there some way in javascript that when I do an ajax request for the file, I can show a progress bar based on the size of the file? (i.e. if the client has retrieved 500KB of it, the progress bar shows 50%,etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show progress bar while loading, using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MDN page about [Monitoring Progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);

oReq.open();

// ...

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;  // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
  alert("The transfer is complete.");
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
  alert("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  alert("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}
```