# Ajax loading bar function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know there are a few post about this but they dont cover what i need to achieve.

I'm trying to get the youtubelike loading bar to work properly.

And i found this :

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        tmp[i] = 'hue';
    }
    data[i] = tmp;
};

       xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                var percentComplete = 0; <--------------------------added this
                $('.progress').removeClass('hide');<----------------and this
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                        $('.progress').css({
                            width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                        });
                        if (percentComplete === 1) {
                            $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        console.log(percentComplete);

                        $('.progress').css({
                            width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                            });
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            }
```

I have added 2 lines because it would only work once as the hidden value was not being removed after the completion. Also put the width back to 0. I also like the fact that it seams to be calculating the real percentage of the event.

This is working great. Howerver, i want to turn this into a function that can be called for all my ajax call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = ($(this).attr("id"));
        var container = ($(this).attr("data-container"));
        var link = ($(this).attr("href"));
        var text = ($(this).text());
        var html = ($(this).html());
        MY_LOADING_BAR_FUNCTION();<-----------------------------------Here i guess?
        $.ajax({

            url: 'ajax-php.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 'action': 'click', 'id': id, 'text': text, 'link': link, 'html': html },
            success: function (data, status) {
                if (container == '#formbox') {
                    $("#screen").addClass("visible");
                }
                $(container).html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }
        }); // end ajax call
    }); // end on click
}); // en document ready
```

But i also ran across the Ajax setup that looks like this.

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    complete : function() {

    }
});
```

Right now i got it to work by putting the entire code of the `xhr: function ()` inside my ajax call. But i dont want to do it every time.

So these are the 2 options i have found that could work but i cant get them to work the way i want. I try to make a `MY_LOADING_BAR_FUNCTION()` but i'm getting a deprecated error.

Can anyone tell me how to make this work please.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Like youtube? This is not a single request. This is many requests. For first all requests should add into "queue". And after success, each request should update loading bar. For improved you can set percentage weight of each request.

Comment: Huh No! this is one single request sending a Json array to a php file!?

Answer (score 2):

It's late to reply, but its worth to share some knowledge, so others may get help from it.

You can extend jQuery AJAX XHR object as below.

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function ()
{
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            //Do something with upload progress
            console.log('percent uploaded: ' + (percentComplete * 100));
        }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            //Do something with download progress
            console.log('percent downloaded: ' + (percentComplete * 100));
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
}
```