# How to show live script output during AJAX form submit request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to show "Live Feedback" on a script using jQuery?

I have a `button` that I use to submit a form for processing.  Processing takes a long time.  I want to have a `<div id="progress"></div>` where I show live progress report of what order processing script is doing.  If all goes well I want to redirect to the View Order script, and if not, just show the progress report (not redirect to view order)

How?  Currently I have this:

```
$("#placeorderbutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.innerHTML = 'Placing Order...';
    this.disabled = true; 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process_order.php',
        data: $('form#order').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#main").load('view_order.php');            
        }
    });
});
```

and even though I have print statements in my `process_order` file, they are not being displayed anywhere on the screen.  Well, of course not ... I don't know how to build my jQuery/AJAX to make them show.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: success will only fire once the ajax is fully completed and successful.

Comment: in other words, what I seek is impossible, correct?

Comment: I would normally fire the process in one ajax call then fire up another ajax on a timer to check the status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show progress bar while loading, using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax)

Comment: I wonder if instead I can just redirect to a page that loads (slowly) showing the progress, and once it's done, redirect again to view order (no AJAX used)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to start the long process and then start a timer to poll the status.  Keep in mind it doesn't take much for this to become more expensive than it's worth.

```
$("#placeorderbutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.innerHTML = 'Placing Order...';
    this.disabled = true; 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process_order.php',
        data: $('form#order').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#main").load('view_order.php');            
        }
    });
    setTimer($.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'view_order.php',
        data: $('form#order').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#main").append(data);            
        }
    }), 30000);  //check every 30 Seconds
});
```