# AJAX progress bar of load script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a big problem to make a progress bar in AJAX. The whole page is in AJAX, inside one of the webpage is AJAX which loads a function to get some big rows from the database.

I tried to make progress bar in this script in a foreach loop a flush() method and by writing/reading to $_SESSION, but still nothing. I really tried everything I don`t know how to do this. Need only this to complete my project. Could someone help me with this?

It is anyway which script I want to load, how is the template for this progress bar to use it in GET or POST ajax, for any AJAX.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            
            $(document).on('click','#save',function () {
                setTimeout(getProgress,1000);
              $(this).text('Pobieram analizę...');
              $.urlParam = function(name){
             var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
            }
        var id = $.urlParam('id');
        var idt = $.urlParam('idt');
                  $.ajax({
                                 url: "views/getresults.php?id="+id+"&idt="+idt,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#loadresults").append(data);
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(getProgress,3000);
            return false;
            });
            function getProgress(){
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'views/listen.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data<=100 && data>=0){
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#loadresults').html('<div id="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:'+ (data / 100)*100 +'%">'+ data + '/' +100+'</div></div>');
                            setTimeout(getProgress,1000);
                            console.log('Repeat');
                        } else {
                            $('#loadresults').text('Pobieram dane');
                            console.log('End');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
```

and here is a getresults.php

```
    foreach($result as $resul) {
    $count++;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $count;
    $_SESSION['total'] = 100;
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
}
unset($_SESSION['progress']);
```

and a get progress function listen.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo (!empty($_SESSION['progress']) ? $_SESSION['progress'] : '');

if (!empty($_SESSION['progress']) && $_SESSION['progress'] >= $_SESSION['total']) {
    unset($_SESSION['progress']);
}

?>
```

Comment: What you had tried ?

Comment: mostly this session method, any flush and with somthing with spinner in html5

Comment: I am new in ajax, i made a lot work, but this progress bar is...

Comment: Please display your code so we can get idea

Comment: and another thing is that i know exacly a number of all count results of foreach loop

Comment: you want to display progess bar until any function is running, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095108/5060008 this will help you.

Comment: exacly foreach loop i wanna progress bar for example 1/100 done. 2/100 done. if is 100/100 or is just done becouse i can count foreach loop.

Comment: How to send to page every foreach loop is done from this script getresult.php a some message or somthing to display in main page where I start ajax job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing and reading session doesn't work because the standard behavior of PHP is to lock the session file while your main code is being executed.

Try to create a file and update the its content with the percentage done during the execution of your function. Something like:

```
<?php
function slowFunction() {
    $file = uniqid();
    file_put_contents($file, 0);
    // Long while that makes your stuff
    // you have to know how many loops you will make to calculate the progress
    $total = 100;
    $done = 0;
    while($done < $total) {
        $done++;
        // You may want not to write to the file every time to minimize changes of being writing the file 
        // at the same time your ajax page is fetching it, i'll let it to you...
        $progress = $done / $total;
        file_put_contents($file, $progress);
    }
    unlink($file); // Remove your progress file
}
```

?>

Comment: so its same thing as session but using file yes ?

Comment: could you implement this code to my code to better understand ?

Comment: Sorry, when I saw your question there were no code. Yes, it is same thing as session but using files. Your function "getProgress" have to listen to that file, so, you have to pass the its name instead of "listen.php".

Comment: how to get this in my ajax start function ? ok in foreach loop i got this add number in file and how to get the same as listen ?

Comment: implement this function inside foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the progress of the data download from ajax. Once you request you to the server, the next response will be only after fetching the data or when the error occurs.

The solution to you is, get the data as fractions. Such as first download the 1/10th of the data, and in the success callback, recursively call the ajax again requesting the 2/10th data. On each success callback, you could change the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Server Side Events or Long polling as options