# How to implement progress bar during HTTP Client request call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, http, asp.net-core

Just a question I'm confused about how I could achieve this. I just want to implement progress bar on how long the response from HTTP client request call. I saw a lot of tutorials on how to implement this progress bar but it all centered to a file being downloaded from the server. I want to ask what would be the best approach to do this.

This is my situation. I have a web API that generates a zip file that contains multiple word file that was generated base on the parameters from the calling site. Basically, a lot of things happening from pulling the records from the database and generating these files that's why it took time for the response to be sent and I want to at least show progress bar out of this so that when our user click the button to generate this file they can see the progress of the report to be generated.

This is how i consume the API:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri ("MYBASEURI");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/zip"));
    var content = new StringContent(strModel, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("API_URI", content);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ExceptionResponse ex = await response.ExceptionResponse();
        return null;
    }
    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    return File(data, "application/zip", "File.zip");
}
```

I'm calling this method on form submit since it has parameters needed for the report to generate.

Comment: If you are doing ajaxCall to call API then you can show progress bar on UI. when ajaxStart event trigger then show gif image and when ajaxStop event trigger then hide gif image.

Comment: is it possible to show the specific progress instead of showing an animation of loading?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax

Comment: Why did you add the javascript tag?