# How to Upload Video file showing a progressbar in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, file-upload

I want to upload a video file using PHP and show the progress of the upload via an Progress Bar. But this is more difficult like I thought and I tried to put the pieces I've found together but unfortunately, I didn't found a working piece of code that has the needed PHP, Ajax and HTML code altogether, so I've tried to put different pieces together. [@fahad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2760108/fahad)

```
'''
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include 'public/menubar.php'; ?>

<script src="assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($,W,D) {
        var JQUERY4U = {};
        JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
            setupFormValidation: function() {
                //form validation rules
                $("#form-validation").validate({
                    rules: {
                        cat_id              : "required",
                        video_title         : "required",
                        video_duration      : "required",
                        video_description   : "required",
                        youtube             : "required",
                        url_source          : "required",
                        video               : "required",
                        image               : "required",
                        video_thumbnail     : "required"                     
                    },

                     messages: { 
                        cat_id              : "Please fill out this field!",
                        video_title         : "Please fill out this field!",
                        video_duration      : "Please fill out this field!",
                        video_description   : "Please fill out this field!",
                        youtube             : "Please fill out this field!",
                        url_source          : "Please fill out this field!",
                        video               : "Please fill out this field!",
                        image               : "Please fill out this field!",
                        video_thumbnail     : "Please fill out this field!"

                    },
                    errorElement : 'div',
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }

                });
            }
        }

        //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
        $(D).ready(function($) {
            JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);

</script>

<?php include 'public/add-video-form.php'; ?>
<?php include('public/footer.php'); ?>

'''
```

Comment: You will have to use AJAX to upload a file if you want to show the progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload form is the name of the form .. the ("progressBar") is ur progress bar 
work with it and if u have any problem, let me know

```
function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

$('#uploadForm').submit((event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    var form = document.getElementById("uploadForm"),
        formdata = new FormData(form);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload-media");
    ajax.send(formdata);

    function formatBytes(bytes, decimals) {
        if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
        var k = 1024,
            dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals || 2,
            sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
            i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
        return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
    }

    function progressHandler(event) {
        _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = `Uploaded ${formatBytes(event.loaded)} of ${formatBytes(event.total)}`;
        var percent = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
        _("progressBar").style.width = `${Math.round(percent)}%`;
        _("status").innerHTML = `${Math.round(percent)}% uploaded... please wait`;
        _('submit').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    }

    function completeHandler(event) {
        var res = JSON.parse(event.target.response);
        _("titleView").innerHTML = `${res.title}`;
        _('total').innerHTML = `${formatBytes(res.fileSize)}`;
        _("statuses").innerHTML = `video Uploaded successfully`;
        _("status").innerHTML = `video Uploaded successfully file name is ${res.video}`;
        _("imgplace").innerHTML = `<img src="thumbnail/${res.thumbnail}">`;
        _("progressBar").style.width = "0";
        _("uploadForm").reset();
        _("submit").removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

    }

    function errorHandler(event) {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    }

    function abortHandler(event) {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
    }
})
```

Comment: can you send me your email. i want to talk - check me  on lastnode43@gmail.com

Comment: check now @Nasirudeen Olohundare my email : lastnode43@gmail.com

Comment: check now  my email : lastnode43@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript listening on the progress event of the ajax

Here is one of the previous question solved: [How to show progress bar while loading, using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax)