# how to display php progressbar when reading data using php

Tags: php

The code below displays a percentage progress bar for the php long  running code below and its working fine.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $total = 25;
    $i = 0;

    echo json_encode(array('progress' => 0, 'count' => $i, 'total' => $total));
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    while ($i < $total) {

        $i++;
echo json_encode(array('progress' => (($i/$total)*100), 'count' => $i, 'total' => $total));
        flush();
        ob_flush();

        sleep(1);



    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

Now I want to display a progressbar percent when scanning a directory.

Here is the working code for scanning directory

```
function sk($path){
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        $files = glob($path ."/*");

            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo "$file"  . "<br>";

                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    sk("$file");
                }
            }

    } else {
        echo "folder does not exist.";
    }
}

sk("C:/xampp/htdocs/data");
```

**My problem is here:**

when I pass the directory function into the **while loop** as per code below, **the progressbar percent stops counting** on the front end via ajax call
can someone help me out.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $total = 25;
    $i = 0;

    echo json_encode(array('progress' => 0, 'count' => $i, 'total' => $total));
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    while ($i < $total) {
        $i++;

// pass directory functions
function sk($path){
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)){
        $files = glob($path ."/*");

            foreach($files as $file){
                if(is_file("$file")){
                    // Display only filename
                    echo "$file"  . "<br>";

                } else if(is_dir("$file")){
                    sk("$file");
                }
            }

    } else {
        echo "folder does not exist.";
    }
}

sk("C:/xampp/htdocs/data");





echo json_encode(array('progress' => (($i/$total)*100), 'count' => $i, 'total' => $total));
        flush();
        ob_flush();

        sleep(1);



    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get it working

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

source: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax)