# Return Razor Page in Ajax (IActionResult) result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

My netcoreapp3.1 Server does some long lasting things (calculating statisics) in background. The page regularly asks for results per ajax. How can I return either the progress or the page html?

```
 public IActionResult GetTaskResult(string guid)
    {
        ExtensionTask task;
        if(!Program.ExtensionTaskManager.TaskFinished(guid,out task))
        {
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { finished = false, progress = task.Instance.Progress }));
        }
        else
        {
           var html = // how to render the page to this var ???

           return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { finished = true,pageHtml = html  }));  
        }
    }
```

I can workaround that problem querying a normal routed view and just return empty page when not finished, but this does not seem a smooth solution.

Comment: You can try to use a [event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095002/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-loading-using-ajax) to add a porgress.

Comment: Simply: `return Page();` will send back your Razor page.